# Getting error Related model 'auth.User' cannot be resolved when running LogEntry.log_action()

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin

I'm writing an import script to make CSVs into models in my Django website. I want these creations to appear in the "history" in the Django admin, so I wrote this function that should log the creation of the object.

```
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry, ADDITION
def log_creation(created_object, message, uid=1):
    #Doesn't work :(
    LogEntry.objects.log_action(
            user_id=uid,
            content_type_id=get_content_type_for_model(created_object).pk,
            object_id=created_object.pk,
            object_repr=force_text(created_object),
            action_flag=ADDITION,
            change_message=message
        )
```

I mostly copied it off [this built in function](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0207bdd2d4157c542c981264c86706b78ca246e9/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L692) in the admin.

However, if I run it with a newly created object as input, I get this error

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Users/arya/PycharmProjects/PROJECTNAME/importers/plot-importer.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/arya/PycharmProjects/PROJECTNAME/importers/plot-importer.py", line 118, in <module>
    import_plots(plot_csv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 145, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reversion/revisions.py", line 297, in do_revision_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/arya/PycharmProjects/PROJECTNAME/importers/plot-importer.py", line 106, in import_plots
    log_creation(created_plot, message="Created plot through importer")
  File "/Users/arya/PycharmProjects/PROJECTNAME/importers/plot-importer.py", line 26, in log_creation
    change_message=message
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/models.py", line 24, in log_action
    e.save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 710, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 738, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 822, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 861, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 920, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 962, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 920, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1940, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.related_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1886, in related_field
    return self.foreign_related_fields[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1620, in foreign_related_fields
    return tuple(rhs_field for lhs_field, rhs_field in self.related_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1607, in related_fields
    self._related_fields = self.resolve_related_fields()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1592, in resolve_related_fields
    raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.rel.to)
ValueError: Related model 'auth.User' cannot be resolved

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any idea how to avoid this?